# post.php X-Editable save data to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

what code should be written to the post.php, that information is stored in the database but just is recorded only is array

```
<a data-original-title="access" data-pk="1" data-type="checklist" data-value="" id="access"></a>


    $(".editable-form #access").editable({
      source: [
     {value: 1,text: "a"},
     {value: 2,text: "b"},
     {value: 3,text: "c"},
     {value: 4,text: "d"},
     {value: 5,text: "f"}
      ],
        url:"post.php",
        name: "access"
    });


post.php

        if($_POST['name']=='access'){
            $pk = $_POST['pk'];
            $value=$_POST['value'];

              //when i do echo $value result type array 

              //but i want just value = { 0: "1", 1: "2", 2: "3", 3: "4" }

     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE `books` SET `access`='$value' WHERE `id`='$pk'");   
          }
```

Comment: Whats your problem? You would write an array to database? But instead using a varchar/text field you would add each array entry to different ceil?

Comment: When I save the data storage array but I want to get this output value = { 0: "1", 1: "2", 2: "3", 3: "4" }

Comment: Try `echo json_encode($value);`

Comment: I tried but the output will be ["1", "5"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
json_encode(array(1, 2, 3, 4), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

returns

```
{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4}
```

Comment: Now, how do I separate the one I use and the amount of each separate

Comment: What do you want? You would seperate the result above and the amount of all values?

Comment: [{"id":2, "name":"Bob", "phone":"555-123-4567"}]

Comment: how to  $id=2;  $name=bob ; $phone=555;

Comment: you mean decoding json to variables?